# Read Write Excel File in c#

Tags: c#, user-interface

I am bit confused while reading and writing Excel file with C#. I am using Interop.Excel.dll in my applicaiton.

Now this is working fine in my local machine. And I have installed MS Excel.
But when I am running this app **on server where MS Excel is not installed** it is generating an exception.

Do I need to install MS Excel though I have referenced the dll.

Please guide me.

Here is the exception.

```
===================START=====================
    10/27/2012 7:48:52 PM
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
       at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
       at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
       at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
       at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
       at ImpExpExcelFile.Form1.generateExcel(String loginId, String fileName, DataSet newValues)
    ====================END======================
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Need to install MS Excel there, I guess not any other idea for this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771194/microsoft-office-interop-excel-dll-server-doesnot-have-excel-installed ---

Comment: Well, if your code tries to get a handle on an excel application object and there is no Excel application on the machine then there is nothing to get a handle to.

Comment: Have a look at ClosedXML - http://closedxml.codeplex.com/ . Quote: _ClosedXML allows you to create Excel 2007/2010 files without the Excel application. The typical example is creating Excel reports on a web server._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ofc u need install MS Excel. Interop.Excel.dll is only interfaces wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

It is Mandatory to install Excel.  Install and then Try again. Wont work w/o Excel

Answer (score 0):

I work at Expected Behavior, and we've got an HTML to Excel API called DocRaptor that can convert HTML to Excel with no need to have a server-side installation of Excel.

DocRaptor is a Ruby on Rails application, but you can use C# to generate Excel documents with an HTTP POST request.

Here's a link to DocRaptor's homepage:
[DocRaptor](http://docraptor.com/)

And a link to our C# example code:
[DocRaptor C# Example](http://docraptor.com/documentation/examples_csharp)